# Clickable banner image in WiX dialog

Tags: user-interface, wix, wix3.5, banner

I would like to put an image banner on one of my WiX dialogs that when clicked opens a web page for our product support, in case users have trouble with the installation. I think I know how to open the web page but the problem is registering the click event. Is there a way to do this?

From my own attempts I've concluded that a "bitmap" type control won't let you detect clicks. Do I have any other options, like making a pushbutton with a picture on it and hiding the borders so it looks good? I've not been successful with this.

I'm using WiX 3.5.

Comment: [This article](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/careful-with-that-hyperlink-on-your-msi-dialog/index.htm) should help you understand the underlying story and the current approach to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do what you want with internal MSI UI for which WiX provides interface.

You can create a button with image on it but you can't hide the borders of the button.

---

Starting from Windows Installer 4.5, there's ability to include *custom UI* elements, see [Using an Embedded UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for reference. Another option is using [External UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370053%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), where you develop UI as a regular application and handle notification messages from MSI.